# Get every other row in SQL Server without using ROW_NUMBER(): Or... How is my row_number() wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My company uses **GoldMine CRM** (on **SQL** Server), and I'm writing a query to find duplicate records. The query is great, but it returns two rows for each duplicate, and I only need one. However, I can't seem to use `Row_Number()` at all - it always returns a blank column. Here's my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT 
       c11.company AS Company1,
       c12.company AS Company2,
       c11.phone1 AS DuplicatePhone,
       c11.address1 AS C1Address1,
       c12.address1 AS C2Address1,
       c11.zip AS Zip1,
       c12.zip AS Zip2,
       c11.contact AS Contact_1,
       c12.contact AS Contact_2,
       SUBSTRING(c11.company, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', c11.company)) AS C1_Firstword,
       SUBSTRING(c12.company, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', c12.company)) AS C2_Firstword,
       c11.accountno AS Acctno1,
       c12.accountno AS Acctno2
FROM db.contact1 AS c11
INNER JOIN db.contact1 AS c12
ON c11.phone1 = c12.phone1 
WHERE c11.state = 'MA'
AND c12.state = 'MA'
AND c11.phone1 IS NOT NULL
AND c11.phone1 <> ''
AND c11.accountno <> c12.accountno) AS foo

WHERE (PATINDEX('%' + foo.C1_Firstword + '%', foo.company2) > 0
OR PATINDEX('%' + foo.C2_Firstword + '%', foo.company1) > 0)
ORDER BY foo.DuplicatePhone
```

The query first looks for records with the same phone number, and then looks for similarities in the company name (sometimes our contacts share a phone number without being duplicates, but it's common to find duplicates where one name is 'John Smith Enterprises' and the other 'Smith Enterprises')

I've tried every iteration of ROW_NUMBER() in this query and in a far simpler one, eg:

```
SELECT c1.accountno, c1.company, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c1.Accountno ASC) row_num
FROM bpmain1.dbo.contact1 c1
WHERE c1.state = 'MA'
```

... and I always get a blank column. My theory is that the **SQL** panel in **GoldMine** is stopping me from using it, since the results that I get back from **GoldMine** always include a column 'Row' that's numbered (As though **GoldMine** "conveniently" wraps every query with an empty `ROW_NUMBER()` clause.)

So, I end up with two rows for each duplicate instance, and I only need one - it doesn't matter which one. The point of using `ROW_NUMBER()` was to get me every other result. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `where` conditions:

```
FROM db.contact1 c11 INNER JOIN
     db.contact1 c12
     ON c11.phone1 = c12.phone1 AND c11.state = c12.state
WHERE c11.state = 'MA' AND
      c11.phone1 <> '' AND
      c11.accountno < c12.accountno
--------------------^ this is the key change
```

That is, you don't need to remove duplicates.  Just don't generate them in the first place by returning the contacts in account order.

Note that the condition `c11.phone1 IS NOT NULL` is redundant.  Both the `JOIN` conditions and the `<> ''` filter out `NULL` values.

Comment: Thanks on both counts!